# starting an activity where user left it

Tags: android, animation

I have the following code:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

private boolean animated ;

private Handler handler1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (!isPreviouslyLoggedIn()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final TextView revolution=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final Button login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        final Button signUp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);

        login.setOnClickListener(loginListener);
        signUp.setOnClickListener(signUpListener);

        if (!animated) {
            animated = true;
            revolution.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            signUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100, 0);   
            slide.setDuration(1000);
            image.startAnimation(slide);

            handler1 = new Handler();

            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    revolution.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    signUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            },1200);
        }
    }

    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

When the user clicks on one of the buttons, it leads him to a different activity in the same app. However, when the user clicks back from the next activity, the animation is started again. How can I prevent the animation from showing again as i want it to occur only once when user opens the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application` class.Declare a boolean var in it and set it "true" before starting second Activity.In your onCreate() of first Activity check this boolean and do animation only it is false(it means that user has not started second activity yet).For example create class with name `App` in your package:

```
    public class App extends Application{    

    private static boolean animated;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        animated = false;
    }

    public static boolean getAnimated(){
        return animated;
    }

    public static void setAnimated(boolean animated1){
        animated = animated1;
    }

}
```

Register `App` in `manifest`:

```
<application
        android:icon= ...
        android:label= ...
        android:name="yourpackage.name.App" >
```

(I suppose that your package name is :"yourpackage.name")

Now change your code like this:

```
if (!App.getAnimated()) {
            App.setAnimated(true);
            revolution.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            signUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ...
```

Or you can use `sharedpreferences` and retrieve a boolean from it when you want to start animation.You have to set it's default value "false" and when user start second Activity,you have to set it "true".

Comment: I have declared a boolean by stating `private boolean animated;`. Later, when the user clicks a button, I set it to false using `onClickListener`. However, when I click back from the next activity the animation is repeated again. I'm guessing this is because that when the first activity is started again, it re-instantiates the boolean `animated` to false and the previous time when I set it to true is disregarded. How to correct this?

Comment: @user1696863 Do you declare this Boolean in a class that extends `Application`?If yes,do not forget register it in `manifest`.But I guess that you declare it in your Activity.

Comment: I have edited my question to show my current code. I'm still getting the same problem though.

Comment: That worked! thanks! but how exactly does instantiating `animated` from outside `onCreate()` make a difference

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag for this, first time keep the flag `true` and when the user clicks on any of the button, set the flag value to `false`.

Now start the animation if the flag value is `true`.

Comment: instantiate the boolean animated variable outside the 'onCreate' method of the activity.